# HOW can I undo this cp command on Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have done this command `find ../JD/ -name '1*.*' -exec cp ./testdummy.txt {} \;`  and now I must realize that all my 68 file begining with `1` in directory ./JD are overwritten with testdummy.txt. Is there a way to get the originate files back with the corresponding filenames?

Comment: You have a backup of your data, don't you? If you don't, now is a good time to start keeping one. And no, getting data back on ext filesystems is difficult to impossible.

Comment: what were you trying to accomplish with that command? ... where did you get it?

Comment: I wanted to make a dummy tree with testdummy.txt with all the file names. But I forgot that the {} has the whole path info also.

Comment: @dirkt it is not an ext fs but it is an USB  HDD with NTFS mounted on Ubuntu

Comment: NTFS has restore points, but I have no idea if these are used from within Linux (likely not). If you have used the HDD on Windows, you may be lucky. Google "NTFS recover overwritten file" etc. (Also, for the future, look up `basename`).

Comment: @dirkt thanks yes `basename` is the solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the originate files back with the corresponding filenames?

I'm afraid without a backup, that will be impossible.

Even if the file contents still should be lying around in unused (not going to be the case unless you've got a copy-on-write file system, and even then, not universally the case), not yet reclaimed/discarded blocks, the filename metadata is lost and gone.

Comment: thanks yes the filenames are away but I am trying with EASUS Data recovery Tool, where I could find the Files as "FILENAME_LOST(2).mkv"

Comment: I still do know the originale filename and its corresponding filesize, so I try to match it by filesize to get the originale filename.